# Angularjs $q.all with pre-flight request resolves after OPTIONS request

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, preflight

I have multiple delete requests that are preceded by an `OPTIONS` pre-flight request. But the control gets in the then of `$q.all` after `OPTIONS` request. Here is my code:

```
companyMasterC.confirmDelete = function(ev, text) {
     simpleDialog.verifyDelete(ev, text).then(function() {
         companyMasterC.deletePromise = companyMasterC.deleteSelected().then(function(response) {
              companyMasterC.getCompanies();
          }, function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
          });
     });
};

companyMasterC.deleteSelected = function(){
   var promises = companyMasterC.selectedRows.map(function(selectedRow) {
       return company.delete({id:selectedRow.id});
   });
   return $q.all(promises);
};
```

So here is what's happening in the Network tab: First, `OPTIONS` request is performed, then `GET` request is performed `companyMasterC.getCompanies();`
which should perform when `DELETE` requests have been performed. And after the `GET` request `DELETE` requests are performed.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
return company.delete({id:selectedRow.id});
```

to

```
return company.delete({id:selectedRow.id}).$promise;
```

Modified Code:

```
companyMasterC.confirmDelete = function(ev, text) {
     simpleDialog.verifyDelete(ev, text).then(function() {
         companyMasterC.deletePromise = companyMasterC.deleteSelected().then(function(response) {
              companyMasterC.getCompanies();
          }, function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
          });
     });
};

companyMasterC.deleteSelected = function(){
   var promises = companyMasterC.selectedRows.map(function(selectedRow) {
       return company.delete({id:selectedRow.id}).$promise;
   });
   return $q.all(promises);
};
```

Comment: The issue is solved with this, but company.delete({id:selectedRow.id}) is already a promise. So why by adding $promise.